# how to connect to solaris server from citrix metaframe server for windows

Tags: citrix

I want to know the solution for this particular sitauation,
There are thin clients at One location which uses Citrix MetaFrame server to get connected to Windows servers situated at second location, at second location there are few Solaris servers also, can the thin clients at location One, access the Solaris server via Metaframe server(meant for windows)?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to connect? Putty runs fine on Metaframe, so you can SSH to the Solaris boxes.

Comment: I want to get the Sloaris Application published on Windows Citrix metaframe server so that my windows thin clients can use the solaris application, can I? I hear from somebody, by installing Citrix connector on Sloaris box we can get the solaris application published on Windows Metaframe server and windows thin client can use the same.